# Synchronous functions in Node js

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js and I got stuck at a very basic problem.
I have couple of functions where I use the output of one function as a query param in the next param

```
function getCdTypeByValue (table_name,kpi_type){
//some query runs here
return id
}
insertInsight = function(req,res){
var id = getCdTypeByValue (table_name,kpi_type);
//use id in a query for insert

}
```

In my code the insert statement in insertInsight , needs the id returned from getCdTypeByValue.
So , I need this to be a synchronous call , what are the best practises for nodejs to do this.

Comment: Learn how to use Promises and `await`.

Comment: As @PatrickHund suggests please have a look at that post to learn about `Promise` and `async/await` patterns. Then, when you are very confident look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585554/758836, where I suggest a more complex approach with `Promise.all` to resolve multiple asynchronous calls.

Comment: If the underlying operation (like a database query) is asynchronous, then there is NO way to turn that into a synchronous operation and return the value directly from your function.  You simply can't.  Use promises.  See the question yours has been marked a dup of for a full description of your options.